# Closing a Tornado handler

Tags: python, handler, tornado, self

I have a doubt.

I have this part of code:

```
#Code for retrieving the MAC address of the node
    como_url = "".join(['http://', options.como_address, ':', options.como_port,
                        '/ztc_config?netid=', netid,
                        '&opcode_group=', opcodegroupr, 
                        '&opcode=', opcoder, '&start=-5m&end=-1s'])

    print como_url

    http_client = AsyncHTTPClient()
    response = yield tornado.gen.Task(http_client.fetch, como_url)

    ret = {}
    if response.error:
        ret['error'] = 'Error while retrieving the response'
        self.write(tornado.escape.json_encode(ret))
    else:
        for line in response.body.split("\n"):
            if line != "": 
                value = int(line.split(" ")[6])
                ret['response'] = value
        self.write(tornado.escape.json_encode(ret))
```

and I want that, if the response from the server is null, the handler is closed.

I don't know if this

```
 if response.error:
        ret['error'] = 'Error while retrieving the response'
        self.write(tornado.escape.json_encode(ret))
```

is correct to close the handler and return in the page. Or if I have to do a self.finish.....

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is:

```
if response.error:
        ret['error'] = 'Error while retrieving the response'
        self.write(tornado.escape.json_encode(ret))
        self.finish()
```